# Количество совпадений в массивах int[] в posgreeSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, запрос

Есть ли способ подсчитать количество совпадений в двух массивах int[] в posgreesql? Задача состоит в следующем, в таблице `result` есть поля `ar1` и `ar2` которые содержат целочисленные массивы размерностью 5. Также есть два массива, по которым производится поиск, скажем `data1` и `data2`, также размерностью 5.

```
CREATE TABLE result
(ar1 int[],
ar2 int[]);

CREATE TABLE data
(data1 int[],
data2 int[]);

INSERT INTO data (data1, data2) VALUES (ARRAY[90,31,27,45,1], ARRAY[32,72,101,13,74]);

INSERT INTO result (ar1, ar2) VALUES 
(ARRAY[90,55,31,3,21], ARRAY[91,72,54,37,66]), 
(ARRAY[32,91,13,52,21], ARRAY[65,1,66,78,26]), 
(ARRAY[55,85,46,79,1], ARRAY[14,12,86,74,51]), 
(ARRAY[90,31,27,45,111], ARRAY[32,72,101,13,74]);

________                                                                                                                                                                                           

    SELECT * FROM result;

| ar1             | ar2             |
| --------------- | --------------- |
| 90,55,31,3,21   | 91,72,54,37,66  |
| 32,91,13,52,21  | 65,1,66,78,26   |
| 55,85,46,79,1   | 14,12,86,74,51  |
| 90,31,27,45,111 | 32,72,101,13,74 |

________

    SELECT * FROM DATA;

| data1         | data2           |
| ------------- | --------------- |
| 90,31,27,45,1 | 32,72,101,13,74 |
```

В результате запроса нужно получить те строки таблицы, для которых верно условие
`(ar1 №= data1 = 2 AND ar2 №= data2 = 1) OR (ar1 №= data2 = 2 AND ar2 №= data1 = 1) OR (ar1 №= data1 = 1 AND ar2 №= data2 = 2) OR (ar1 №= data2 = 1 AND ar2 №= data1 = 2)`. Оператор №= в данном случае показывает минимальное количество совпадений. Таким образом результирующая выборка должна будет выглядеть как

```
| ar1             | ar2             |
| --------------- | --------------- |
| 90,55,31,3,21   | 91,72,54,37,66  |
| 32,91,13,52,21  | 65,1,66,78,26   |
| 90,31,27,45,111 | 32,72,101,13,74 |
```

, где в первой строке `ar1 №= data1 = 2 AND ar2 №= data2 = 1`, во второй `ar1 №= data2 = 2 AND ar2 №= data1 = 1`, в третьей `ar1 №= data1 = 4 AND ar2 №= data1 = 5`
Пока что удалось добиться определенного результата конструкцией вида

```
WHERE 
( ar1[1] = ANY(data1) AND ar1[2]= ANY(data1) AND ar2[1]= ANY(data2) ) OR
( ar1[2] = ANY(data1) AND ar1[3]= ANY(data1) AND ar2[1]= ANY(data2) ) OR
( ar1[3] = ANY(data1) AND ar1[4]= ANY(data1) AND ar2[1]= ANY(data2) ) OR
( ar1[4] = ANY(data1) AND ar1[5]= ANY(data1) AND ar2[1]= ANY(data2) ) OR
( ar1[1] = ANY(data1) AND ar1[3]= ANY(data1) AND ar2[1]= ANY(data2) ) OR
( ar1[1] = ANY(data1) AND ar1[4]= ANY(data1) AND ar2[1]= ANY(data2) ) OR
( ar1[1] = ANY(data1) AND ar1[5]= ANY(data1) AND ar2[1]= ANY(data2) ) OR
( ar1[2] = ANY(data1) AND ar1[4]= ANY(data1) AND ar2[1]= ANY(data2) ) OR
( ar1[2] = ANY(data1) AND ar1[5]= ANY(data1) AND ar2[1]= ANY(data2) ) OR
( ar1[3] = ANY(data1) AND ar1[5]= ANY(data1) AND ar2[1]= ANY(data2) )
```

, но для получения желаемого результата её необходимо продублировать еще 19 раз (после 3-х повторов запрос не выполняется).

Comment: Создайте fiddle с таблицей, 3-4 записями, а также таблицу с одной записью с data1 и data2. И покажите требуемый ответ для ТАКИХ данных. Опять же - элементы в каждом массиве уникальны или нет? если нет - как учитывать дубли?

Comment: Добавил fiddle и желаемый результат запроса. Природа данных не предполагает дублей, элементы в массивах уникальны.

Comment: Неясно, почему в итог не попадает запись 3. У неё нужное количество совпадений (одно в первом поле и два во втором). Или нужно ещё и позиционное совпадение?

Comment: Извините, моя ошибка. Исправил, теперь запись 3 не должна входить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотри вот на такую конструкцию:

```sql
WITH 
cte AS (SELECT 1 n UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5),
res1 AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) rn
         FROM result),
res2 AS (SELECT rn, 1 n, ar1[n] ar0
         FROM res1, cte
         UNION ALL
         SELECT rn, 10 n, ar2[n] ar0
         FROM res1, cte ),
data1 AS (SELECT 1 n, data1[n] data0
          FROM data, cte
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 100 n, data2[n] data0
          FROM data, cte)
SELECT res1.ar1, res1.ar2
FROM res2, data1, res1
WHERE ar0=data0
  AND res1.rn=res2.rn
GROUP BY res1.ar1, res1.ar2, res1.rn
HAVING ((LPAD(SUM(res2.n*data1.n)::TEXT,4,'0') ~ '[1-5]00[1-5]') OR (LPAD(SUM(res2.n*data1.n)::TEXT,4,'0') ~ '0[1-5][1-5]0'))
   AND (LPAD(SUM(res2.n*data1.n)::TEXT,4,'0') NOT IN ('1001', '0110'))
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=58ecf7cb43316619100501cdc8ec1c4f)